# My selectAll funtion is not working as it should work

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, typescript

i wrote two funtion select all and manual select , select all selects all the values and disselect values  the manual select is working properly but the select all function is not checking and uncheking the checkboxes on ui here are the respective ts and html, if i am wrong please correct me

```
 selection = new SelectionModel(true, []); // remove on code cleaning
    bulkActionArr = [];
    checkAll: FormControl = new FormControl(false);

    selectAll(event: any, datasource) {
        this.checkAll.setValue(event.checked);
        this.bulkActionArr = [];
        if(event.checked)
        {datasource.forEach(element => {
            this.selection.select(element.id); 
            this.bulkActionArr.push(element.id)});
        }
        
        else {
            this.selection.clear();
            this.bulkActionArr = [];
        }
        console.log('1',this.bulkActionArr);

    }

    manualSelect(id: number, index: number, status: boolean, datasource: any[]) {
        // if(this.checkAll.value){
        //    this.checkAll.setValue(false);
        //    this.bulkActionArr =[]
        // }
        if (status) {
            this.bulkActionArr.push(id);
        } else {
            const indexOfId = this.bulkActionArr.indexOf(id);
            if (indexOfId !== -1) {
                this.bulkActionArr.splice(indexOfId, 1);
            }
        }
        if (this.bulkActionArr.length == datasource.length) {
            console.log(datasource.length);
            this.checkAll.setValue(true);
        }
        else{
            this.checkAll.setValue(false);
        }
        console.log('status',status);
        console.log('2','bulkarr',this.bulkActionArr,'checkall ', this.checkAll.value,'datasource', datasource.length, this.bulkActionArr.length)
    }
pe here
```

```
  <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort matSortActive="id" matSortDisableClear matSortDirection="desc">
        <ng-container matColumnDef="isChecked">
            <th class="isChecked"  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
                <mat-checkbox [formControl]="checkAll" (change)="selectAll($event, dataSource)"></mat-checkbox>
            </th>
            <td class="px-3" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;" class="text-start">
                <mat-checkbox (change)="manualSelect(row.id ,i, $event.checked,dataSource)"></mat-checkbox>
            </td>
        </ng-container>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Angular generally you use "variables" in .ts and binding to the .html. This makes all "more easy".

I imagine that the function of your "bulkActionArr" array is this

```
this.bulkActionArr:boolean[]=this.dataSource.data.map(x=>false);

<td class="px-3" mat-cell *matCellDef="let row; let i = index;" class="text-start">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="bulkActionArr[i]"></mat-checkbox>
</td>
```

So

```
selectAll($event, dataSource){
    this.bulkActionArr.forEach(x=>{
       x=$event;
    })
}
```

When you want to know what element of your dataSource are checked

```
getCheckedRows()
{
    return this.dataSource.data.filter((x:any,i:number)=>this.bulkActionArr[i])
}
```